# Pasar parámetros de una pagina a otra

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

uso un controlador para mostrar la paginas asi:

```
<a href="controller.php?page=pagina"</i></a>
```

el controlador la llama asi:

```
include ("paginas/".$page.".php");
```

en el navegador se ve asi:

```
localhost/controller.php?page=pagina
```

Ahora necesito pasar un parametro de una pagina a otra asi:

```
<a href="controller.php?page=edit_product?id='.$row['id'].'"</a>
```

pero el controlador la envia al navegador asi

```
localhost/controller.php?edit_products?id=99.php
```

Lógicamente no va a existir la pagina

Puedo pasar el parámetro `id` de otra forma?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para pasar mas de un parametro como "Query Parameter" tenes que concatenarlos con el caracter "&".

Proba de esta manera:

```
<a href="controller.php?page=edit_product&id='.$row['id'].'"</a>
```

Despues vas a tener que volver a concatenar esos parametros en tu controller al hacer el include. Algo asi

```
$data = array('id'=>$_GET['id']);
include ("paginas/".$page.".php?".$data);
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Podria crearte una función en tu cotrolador que separe la pagina de los parámetros enviados, de esta manera controlas lo que pasa:

```
//URL que llega al controlador
$url = "page=edit_product";

//Funcion en nuestro controlador que detecta la pagina y sus parametros
function pag($pag=null){
    $a = array();
    $l = explode("?",$pag);//separamos la pagina de los parametros
    $p = explode("=",$l[0]);//extraemos la pagina
    $a['pagina'] = $p[1];//guardamos la pagina en nuestro array
    if(isset($l[1])){
        $t = explode("&",$l[1]);
        $a['parametros'] = array();
        for($i=0; $i<count($t);$i++){
            $x = explode("=",$t[$i]);
            $a['parametros'][$x[0]] = $x[1];
        }
    }else{
        $a['parametros'] = false;
    }
    return $a;

}
```

Nuestro controlador veria algo como esto:

```
array(2) { ["pagina"]=> string(12) "edit_product" ["parametros"]=> bool(false) }
```

ahora cuando llegan parametros se veria algo como esto:

```
//URL que llega al controlador con parametros adicionales
$url = "page=edit_product?id=5&clave1=10&clave2=20&clave3=30";

array(2) { ["pagina"]=> string(12) "edit_product" ["parametros"]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "5" ["clave1"]=> string(2) "10" ["clave2"]=> string(2) "20" ["clave3"]=> string(2) "30" } }
```

ya de ahi en adelante puedes realizar mlas adaptaciones de tu controlador para que pase los parametros a las vistas o modelos.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Veo que le estas pasando mal los parametros.

```
<a href="controller.php?page=edit_product?id='.$row['id'].'"</a>
```

Tienes 2 interrogantes "?", solo es el primer interrogante, si luego deseas pasar mas variables debes utilizar el signo **"&"** y seguido la función que pases por GET.

Pasa los datos de la siguiente manera, seguro que te funciona:

```
<a href="controller.php?page=edit_product&id='.$row['id'].'"</a>
```